# Connect to microsoft sql server (on prem) in Azure notebooks using python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, azure-notebooks

Is it possible to connect to microsoft sql server (on-prem) using pyodbc in azure notebooks? Connecting to an azure sql db is possible but I can't find any documentation on the on-prem scenario.

Comment: Not unless you allow off premises connections to your SQL Server via port forwarded on your router; and if you do you most definitely should be limiting the external IPs to the IP of your Azure host in your firewall.

Comment: @Larnu so there's no possibility with an azure data gateway?

Comment: If you've added the azure host to your domain, then it would work, as then the Azure host operates as if it is part of your LAN, via the WAN.